# Replacing loop in dplyr R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

So I am trying to program function with dplyr withou loop and here is something I do not know how to do

Say we have tv stations (x,y,z) and months (2,3). If I group by this say we get
this output also with summarised numeric value

```
TV  months  value

x    2      52
y    2      87
z    2      65
x    3      180
y    3       36
z    3       99
```

This is for evaluated Brand.

Then I will have many Brands I need to filter to get only those which get value >=0.8*value of evaluated brand & <=1.2*value of evaluated brand

So for example from this down I would only want to filter first two, and this should be done for all months&TV combinations

```
brand  TV MONTH value

sdg     x  2     60
sdfg    x  2     55
shs     x  2     120
sdg     x  2     11
sdga    x  2     5000
```

Comment: I am not getting the `value >= 0.8*value of evaluated brand`  Did you mean the `value >= 0.8*mean(value)`?  Also, I suppose you want to sort the value by brand and take the highest two value rows per brand.  Another doubt is the grouping variables in the original dataset.  Is it brand, TV and month or just brand and TV?

Comment: If you see my example so for combintion (tv =x & and month =2 ) I have value 52. I want to filter brand with value >=0.8*52 & <=1.2*52. No sorting needed at this stage

Comment: Which one of the example represent the input dataset? first or second

Comment: first is input   . I have datasets of many commercial spots and first table for   evaluated brand is result of this    `code`  a<-campaign%>%group_by(TV,month)%>%summarise(Value=sum(BUYING_GRPs)`code`

Comment: I am not following the logic.  May be `left_join(df2, df1, by =c(TV='TV', MONTH='months')) %>% group_by(brand, TV, MONTH) %>% arrange(desc(value.x)) %>% filter(value.x >= 0.8*value.y , value.x <= 1.2*value.y, row_number() %in% 1:2)  %>% select(-value.y)`

Comment: The second table is similar aggregation but there are competitive brand and there are many of them . And I need to filter for each combination of tv and month only those similar in size to the evaluated brand. Then i go on with further calculations.....

Comment: If you have two tables, just as I mentioned do a `left_join` and then `filter` the rows.  From your minimal example, it is hard to know what the expected output is.

Comment: thx Akrun left join for sure can be a way to go. I shoud be able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @akrun said, you need to use a combination of merging and subsetting. Here's a base R solution.

```
m <- merge(df, data, by.x=c("TV", "MONTH"), by.y=c("TV", "months"))
m[m$value.x >= m$value.y*0.8 & m$value.x <= m$value.y*1.2,][,-5]
#  TV MONTH brand value.x
#1  x     2   sdg      60
#2  x     2  sdfg      55
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(TV = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("x", 
"y", "z"), class = "factor"), months = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), value = c(52L, 87L, 65L, 180L, 36L, 99L)), .Names = c("TV", 
"months", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))

df <- structure(list(brand = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("sdfg", 
"sdg", "sdga", "shs"), class = "factor"), TV = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "x", class = "factor"), MONTH = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), value = c(60L, 55L, 120L, 11L, 5000L)), .Names = c("brand", 
"TV", "MONTH", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```